# We need rw_nus and r_network scope permissions again, is it even possible

Tags: linkedin-api

Our site is using `rw_nus` and `r_network` permissions from Linkedin to work properly. We were fetching feeds from Linkedin and were able to post comments and likes. But now we are getting following error:

> error=invalid_scope&error_description=Your+application+has+not+been+authorized+for+the+scope+%22r_fullprofile%22r_network%22rw_nus

We found the [following link](http://codesmith.in/linkedin-restricted-developer-api/) that says:

> Linkedin deprecating rw_nus from API

Is it now even possible to get these permissions once again or its over now? If yes, then how to get approval for them?

Comment: This has all been clearly discussed and blogged about on developer.linkedin.com

Comment: @JustinKominar Could you please share that link here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Deprecation of `rw_nus` permission:**

The `rw_nus` member permission will be deprecated as of May 12, 2015 [Linkedin API changes](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes).  Going forward, if your application shares content on behalf of a LinkedIn member, your application will require the **`w_share`** member permission to be granted.

The new `w_share` permission will grant you the permission to share content on LinkedIn as you could previously, however you will no longer be able to read shared content from a user's LinkedIn feed using the API.

So, if you were using the following link to request an Authorization code

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=rw_nus
```

Now, you’ll have to ue –

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=w_share
```

**How to fix invalid scope authorization error:**

To correct this issue, ensure that the scope parameter in your authorization workflow is no longer requesting any of the following member permissions:

```
r_fullprofile, r_network, r_contactinfo, rw_nus, rw_groups, w_messages
```

For access to these permissions,  you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant [Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) that provides the necessary API access to the required endpoints.

So apply for partner status with LinkedIn, explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets the criteria of **"we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn,"** then one or more endpoints will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

For further details, check this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition).

Comment: Thank you for sharing valuable info. LinkedIn should make their docs better

Comment: The helpful guide.